# How can I center a graphic under a <ul>-based nav menu?

Tags: jquery, css, drop-down-menu

I have a simple, basic CSS drop-down menu and I want to center an arrow graphic under the selected item. Ideally, completely with CSS. I thought about doing this with the *:after* selector, but I'm already using that to draw dividing lines between the menu options:

**HTML:**

```
<ul>
    <li>Option Zero</li>
    <li>Option One Is Longer</li>
    <li class='selected'>Option Two
        <ul class='sub-menu'>
            <li>Sub One</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Option Three Is Not the Best</li>
</ul>
<div class='arrowholder'>
    <div class='arrow'></div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
* {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing:    border-box;
    box-sizing:         border-box;
}

ul {
    list - style: none;
    width: 100 % ;
    background: red;
    height: 50px;
    padding: 10px 10px 0 10px;
    margin: 0px;
}
li {
    float: left;
    margin - top: 10px;
}
li: after {
    content: "|";
    margin: 0 8px;
}.sub - menu {
    display: none;
}

.arrowholder {
    clear: both;
    width: 100 % ;
    background: green;
    height: 50px;
}
.arrow {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background: url(http: //upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/1/1c/Up_Arrow_Icon.png) no-repeat;border:solid 1px white;
}
```

**JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pnoeric/MrW58/2/**

I've already sorted out a jQuery-based solution (you'll see it on the fiddle) but for some reason, it's not working cross-browser for me... the position() method is returning different values in Chrome vs Firefox so it's not reliable.

**UPDATE:** grrr, my jQuery-based solution works perfectly when the Chrome JavaScript Console isn't open. When that's open, the jQuery position() method gets confused and returns weird values. Sooo... I have a solution, the jQuery-based solution does it, I just have to close the developer console.

Ideally I'm looking for a solution that is 100% CSS, and barring that, a little bit of supporting jQuery. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a pseudo class on the .selected li that holds that arrow. Example:

```
.selected:after {
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    background:url(http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/1/1c/Up_Arrow_Icon.png) no-repeat; 
    top:30px;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-25px;
    border:solid 1px white;
}
```

Just be sure to give your list item position:relative.

Here's a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/9u2J6/4/

Comment: Your fiddle gets rid of the divider after "Option Two"-- is that what you intended?

Comment: Oops, didn't see there was a pseudo class already being used for a pipe character divider. Easy fix though, just use border instead. Updated demo: http://jsfiddle.net/9u2J6/4/

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply apply a background-image to each li, use background-position:bottom center; to position the arrow, background-repeat:no-repeat; and then use padding-bottom so the content doesn't overlap the arrow.

Comment: I think I understand... so then for the .selected item, I would alter the padding-bottom so the arrow shows? Can you show me in the JSfiddle?

Comment: Update: I tried your solution and while it's very clever and almost perfect, the arrow centers based on the left edge of the title of the menu (the "O" in "Option Two"), not the divider bar that appears just before it. Is there a way to scooch it over a bit; essentially something like `background:position:bottom (center-5px)`?

Comment: Yeah, you can use pixel values to set the background position.

Comment: Well, that won't really work, since it still has to center itself under the selected item; if I specify absolute pixel values, then the centering disappears. What I really need it to do is center itself and then slide left about 5px to make up for the extra space from the dividing bar. Make sense?

Comment: You could try using % values instead

Answer (score 0):

It turns out my jQuery-based solution works perfectly... as long as Chrome's JavaScript Console panel isn't open. When that's open, the position() method gets confused and it stops functioning. Super frustrating to discover that (so much time wasted) but glad I found it.

Here's the solution... it just manually moves the arrow graphic over to where it needs to be to center it.

```
$(function() {
    p = $('.current').position();
    w = $('.current').width();
    naw = $('.arrow').width();
    f = Math.floor(p.left + (w/2) - (naw/2))-20;
    $('.arrow').css('margin-left', f+'px');
});
```